# Find the roots of the polynomial $A(x)=x^6-21x^5+175x^4-735x^3+1624x^2-1764x+720$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the roots of the polynomial $A(x)=x^6-21x^5+175x^4-735x^3+1624x^2-1764x+720$.

Using the Rational Root Theorem, one can find that the given polynomial factors as $A(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)$. Is there something "fancy" that we can note (maybe about the coefficients) in order to escape the trial and error required by the Rational Root Theorem?

Comment: Not really, I don't think. One can at least use (a simple case of) [Descartes's rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Negative_roots) to rule out negative roots.

Comment: One can observe that $21=\sum_{i=1}^6i$ and $720=\prod_{i=1}^6i$, then make an educated guess.

Comment: One can make "educated guesses" and apply other ad hoc observations. But certainly the Rational Root Theorem is a general statement, and why not apply it. You can also reduce modulo a prime, to find the possible roots, see [this similar question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624402/find-solutions-to-the-polynomial-x4x3-x2-5x4/4624426#4624426), if you like it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, can you clarify what does "reduce modulo a prime" mean and it's application when trying to find roots of a polynomial? I am not familiar with this method and would love to read about it (maybe the OP as well).

Comment: @KaloyanK. Please click on the question of yesterday. In my answer I took $p=2$ (then a factorisation is almost trivial to see, and one of the roots must be also one for the original problem).

Comment: How do you define "fancy"?

Comment: You need six numbers that multiply together to make $720$.  They can't be large unless most of them are $1$, so try $\pm 1$ first.  You find $1$ works but only once.  Similarly once you find the single root at $2$, you know the rest are at least $3$ in absolute value, so the product is already at least $162$.  You don't have to worry about anything larger than $10$ now because the product will be too large.

Comment: I think $6!=720$ is common enough to recognize and start to suspect it's $\prod_{n=1}^6(x-n)$. One sanity check that is consistent before working it out is to reduce the coefficients mod $7$, since this will make $x^6-1 \mod 7$ if our guess is correct, which isn't too hard to do in your head by looking at most of the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind here

1. The signs of the coefficients are strictly alternating, so all real roots (let alone rational ones) [must be positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs). Thereby the trials are cut in half.
2. Suppose you have identified the roots $1$ and $2$ and removed them through synthetic division. You are left with the fourth-degree polynomial

$x^4-18x^3+119x-342x+360=0.$

Now try to equate this with $(x^2-ax+b)^2$ where the cubic terms render $2a=18$ and the quadratic terms render $a^2+2b=119$. Thus $a=9$ and $b=19$. We then get actually

$(x^2-9x+19)^2=x^4-18x^3+119x-342x+\color{blue}{361},$

just missing our target polynomial but still we can render

$(x^2-9x+19)^2=1.$

Thus $x^2-9x+18=0$ or $x^2-9x+20=0$, and solving these quadratic equations gives all four remaining roots.

A more sophisticated version of the method, involving the solution of an eighth-degree equation with roots containing square-root radicals, is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4365954/248217).